# How to communicate properly between java server and gamemaker studio client

Tags: java, game-maker-studio-2

I have created a very very basic java server with tutorials. The goal is to let gamemaker studio 2 clients connect and communicate with that server. I have more experience with GML.
So the server is starting(java) up and the client(GMS2) is connecting succesfully. I have buildin some checks to make sure. If the client send a message to the server, the server never gets it, until the clients disconnect.

this is the java code:

```html
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
 
public class GameServer {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         
     ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6666);
     Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
     
     out.println("hello gamemaker studio: "); //the clients receive this message
    
     while(true) {
     
      System.out.println("in while loop");//the server console prints this message
      
      String string = in.readLine();//keeps stuck on this
      //after client disconnect, all messages the client has sent are displayed in the console
      System.out.println("reading string:" + string);
      if (string == null) { break; }

      out.println("we have received this answer: " + string );
      System.out.println("stopped");
     }
  
    }

}
```

For some reason i don't know it is keeps stuck on this line:
String string = in.readLine();
I crafted a java client to test it. Everything works fine with a java client.
So there has to be something wrong with the gamemaker code

Comment: Does the client send anything before the server does?

Comment: Are you sure that the client flushes their output and that it contains a newline (which `readLine()` is expecting)?

Comment: No, the server sent first the hello message to the client, the client receives that message and displays it. @MickMnemonic In gamemaker i have this to send a message: buffer_seek(buff, buffer_seek_start, 0);
buffer_write(buff, buffer_string, "this is a test");
network_send_raw(server, buff, buffer_tell(buff));

Comment: I think you're not using the java part of the application correctly. I don't think that while should be there - I'm not experienced with Java, but I am with GameMaker, and I'm sure that way of sending messages sends a single packet (you can double check that with a packet sniffer). I'm doing it the same way and have made successful servers. Maybe try connecting with "packet-sender" as well (https://packetsender.com/) so you can validate your Java server.